# How to download blob file into memory stream?

Tags: c#, azure

I've written code which is fetching only first file into memory stream which I need to send on SFTP, so only first file is sent to SFTP & I've 3 files in blobs.
here is my code.

```
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    string str = blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.LocalPath;
    string fileName = blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.LocalPath.Replace("/output/ServiceNowExtract/", "");
    var blobPath = string.Format("{0}", blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.OriginalString);
    CloudBlockBlob blobSNow = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName.Replace(fileName, blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.LocalPath.Replace("/output/", "")));
    string ftpFilePathSNow = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ftpUploadPathSNow, fileName);
    var latestblob = container.ListBlobs();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        // Downloading the blob containt to the memory stream
        blobSNow.DownloadToStream(stream);
        try
        {
            using (var client = new SftpClient(ftpConnectionSNow))
            {
                client.BufferSize = 999424;
                client.Connect();
                stream.Position = 0;
                client.UploadFile(stream, ftpFilePathSNow, true);
                client.Disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `my code is not fetching large file` Is it throwing an exception? Something else?

Comment: there are multiple files on blob, but second file size is of 33 MB that is not fetched by code, but another small file is sent to SFTP which is less than 1 MB.

Comment: `that is not fetched by code` What does that mean?

Comment: Now I kept only 1 file into blob but out of 33MB code is downloading on some parts of it, and size is in kb

Answer (score 3):

Please have a try to use the following code,it works correctly on my side. I test the 4 blobs in the container, the blob constructs as following.

[image]

Demo code:

```
  var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
  CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("output");
  var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
  var ftpConnectionSNow = new ConnectionInfo("HostName", "username", new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username","password"));
  const string ftpUploadPathSNow = "/home/xxx/sftptest4tom"; //sftp path
  foreach (var blob in blobs)
  {
       CloudBlockBlob blobSNow = (CloudBlockBlob) blob;
       var fileName = blobSNow.Name;
       Console.WriteLine($"BlobName:{fileName} ---BlobSize:{blobSNow.Properties.Length}");
       var ftpFilePathSNow = $"{ftpUploadPathSNow}/{fileName}";
       using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
       {
          // Downloading the blob containt to the memory stream
          blobSNow.DownloadToStream(stream);
          try
            {
               using (var client = new SftpClient(ftpConnectionSNow))
               {
                   client.BufferSize = 999424;
                   client.Connect();
                   stream.Position = 0;
                   client.UploadFile(stream, ftpFilePathSNow, true);
                   client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                        // ToDo
            }
       }
  }
```

Check uploaded blobs from the command

[image]